# Extracting scene "bright parts" and flicker in OpenGL scene

Tags: opengl, shader

I've written the following shader to perform a bright pass of my scene so I can extract luminance for later blurring as part of a "glow" effect.

```
// "Bright" pixel shader.

#version 420

uniform sampler2D Map_Diffuse;
uniform float uniform_Threshold;

in vec2 attrib_Fragment_Texture;
out vec4 Out_Colour;

void main(void) 
{
    vec3 luminances = vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722);
    vec4 texel = texture2D(Map_Diffuse, attrib_Fragment_Texture);

    float luminance = dot(luminances, texel.rgb);

    luminance = max(0.0, luminance - uniform_Threshold);

    texel.rgb *= sign(luminance); 
    texel.a = 1.0;

    Out_Colour = texel;
}
```

The bright areas are successfully extracted however there are some unstable features in the scene sometimes, resulting in pixels that flicker on and off for a while.  When this is blurred the effect is more pronounced, with bits of glow kind-of flickering too.  The artifacts occur in, for example, the third image in the screenshot I've posted, where the object is in shadow and so there's far less luminance in the scene.  They're mostly present in transition from away to towards the light of course (during rotation of the object), where the edge is just hitting the light.

[image]

My question is to ask whether there's a way you can detect and mitigate this in the shader.  Note that the bright pass is part of a general down-sample, from screen resolution to 512x512.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could read the surrounding pixels also and do your math based on that.

Kind of like is done [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25254/how-to-get-the-texture-coordinate-of-a-neighbouring-pixel-for-a-blur-shader).

Comment: Yes, the sampler is GL_LINEAR in any case.  It's just that whatever you do, there are always going to be some 1 pixel wide features and these will be unstable as they transition.

Comment: You can for example change the brightness of the spot based on surrounding pixels. That way the "1 pixel"s wouldn't appear unstable but rather would fade in looking controlled.

Comment: OK I changed to a different algorithm for calculating the blur and it seems to be much better (though still not perfect).  I suppose there's no way to stop single bright pixels from appearing in the scene without things like AA and de-noising.  So it's part of the deal.